# Return postgresql query result in a function

Tags: javascript, postgresql, kotlin

I'm right now working on a web API with expressjs, kotlin and PostgreSQL. I organized my project in an object oriented way. I also created a class for the database that makes all frequently called queries available as a function. Example:

```
fun addUser(firstName: String, lastName: String, password: String, classId: Int){
client.query("INSERT INTO users(first_name, last_name, password, class_id) values($1, $2, $3, $4)", arrayOf(firstName, lastName, password, classId));
}
```

This doesn't work however when I'm trying to issue a SELECT query and return the dataset to the function caller since queries are asynchronous. I already tried assigning the result to an attribute of the database object and using it as soon as the value is assigned, but it seems that the value can't be assigned when I'm checking its value permanently. Does anyone know how I could return the value to the function caller?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Not sure why this is tagged as node.js or express, given the example is in Kotlin.

Comment: You're right, I should rather tag it Javascript instead of node and express since the problem with the asynchronous function lays in the ways of javascript.

Comment: node.js might actually be the right tag if you are compiling kotlin to javascript and then running the compiled code in node,js . It would be even better if the question spelled this out.

Comment: Shocked me at first to hear for the first time about Kotlin, but then I looked at the NPM statistics - https://www.npmjs.com/package/kotlin, and no surprise there, nobody is really using it.

Comment: @vitaly-t it's still 'experimental' at least according to the intelli-j UI. And some useful features such as coroutines (which might apply to this question) are still being ironed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using nodejs and the [pg](https://node-postgres.com/) module.

As you said since query function is async you cannot return the result to the caller directly. Traditionally in nodejs the caller passes a callback function to handle the result or the error if there is one.

In Kotlin this would look like:

```kotlin
    client.query(MY_QUERY_TEMPLATE, params) { err, result ->
        if (err != null) {
            // do something with the error
        } else {
            // do something with the result
        }
    }
```

To make this a bit neater you could put your result handler in its own function

```kotlin
fun handleResult(err: dynamic, result: dynamic) {
    // put your code here
}
```

And use it like this:

```kotlin
client.query(MY_QUERY_TEMPLATE, params, ::handleResult)
```

If you don't like this you have another option. The `pg` library can return `Promise`. This abstraction allows you to use method chaining like this:

```kotlin
app.get("/promiseStyle") { req, res ->
    val params = arrayOf(42) // or something...

    fun handleSuccess(result: dynamic) {
        for (row in result.rows) {
            res.write(row.someField)
        }
        res.end()
    }

    fun handleError(error: dynamic) {
        res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
    }

    client.query(MY_QUERY_TEMPLATE, params)
        .then(::handleSuccess)
        .catch(::handleError)
}
```

You may find the following declaration useful for accessing the various pg client functionality:

```kotlin
@JsModule("pg")
external object pg {
    class Client {
        fun query(query: String, params: Array<Any>): dynamic

        fun query(
            query: String, params: Array<Any>, cb: (dynamic, dynamic) -> Unit
        )

        fun connect()
    }
}
```

The postgres client can then be initialized as follows:

```kotlin
val client = pg.Client()
client.connect()
```